# Assign array to class members in order

Tags: c#

I have the following class

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string a {get;set;}
  public string b {get;set;}
  public string c {get;set;}
  public string d {get;set;}
  public string e {get;set;}
  ...
  ...
  public string z {get;set;}
}
```

and the following string array

```
string[] input;
```

I have no way of knowing beforehand the size of the array. The only information I have is that it will be between 1 to 26 in length and all the items are in order. What I need to do is assign the array items in order to the class members as shown below.

```
var myvar = new MyClass();

if(input.length >= 1)
   myvar.a = input[0];
if(input.length >= 2)
   myvar.b = input[1];
...
if(input >=26)
   myvar.z = input[25];
```

Is there any way to do it more elegantly than my method?

Comment: Can you change MyClass to something better than having 27 fields.

Comment: @sylon - Actually, I made it generic to be able to put it out into stack overflow. The real code contains sensitive names for the fields and we would like to be able to access the data using the field name.

Comment: It looks like some kind of "electronic device interacts with a software and sends the data through an array"

Comment: @user1778770 - that is exactly what is happening! :)

Comment: Don't make use of attributes to replace the use of data structures. As @sylon said, give better context of the problem. on seeing this, all you need to have is an array not properties. Just think those are *really* the properties of the class, otherwise change it to appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would wrap it in a method

```
public string GetVal(int index){
  if(input.Length > index)
  {
    return input[index];
  }
  return null;
} 

public string a
{
  get{return GetVal(0);}
}
```

Comment: This way you avoid duplicating the array length check

Comment: This is really helpful. The only downside is that the function will run every time I attempt to access any field value. Is it possible to have the function run only once?

Comment: @user1 I think it would probably be better to leave them as auto-properties, and have one method that reads the array, and pulls out the data, and sets the values of the properties.  There's no need to call the GetValue method more than once for each property.

Comment: Running this function repeatedly should represent very minimal overhead. After all it's only doing a lookup in an array of 27 elements. You can ensure it runs only once by adding a backing field in the properties and run a null check, but that will require the same amount of overhead as the function itself

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this would be helpful at all, and I also don't know if I would consider this "elegant", but you could do something tricky with reflection like this:

```
var myVar = new MyClass();
var properties = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToArray();
for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
{
  properties[i].SetValue(myVar, input[i]);
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why this code is not "elegant"? It looks like it can get the job done. I like TGH's answer but am concerned that his method will run every time I attempt to access a field. Your method has the advantage of running only once.

Comment: For the example you provided, this definitely will get the job done.  I don't know what your real code looks like though.  That's why I have my doubts.  If you could post more, maybe I could help more.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov there you go.

Comment: There might be other properties in the class that might interfere. Should filter to ensure that only the a-z props are targeted

Comment: +1. In real code (if properties named differently) sorting by name may need to be replaced with something else, but as it stands it is good approach for currently stated problem.

Comment: This is a very good answer but I picked TGHs since it may better help someone who stumbles onto this page in future!

Comment: @user1 I like TGH's solution.  I just posted mine because it was completely different, and I didn't know if it would help or not.  There's plenty of rep to go around.  I don't get fussy over it. :)

Answer (score 1):

A robust approach may be to decorate your properties with a custom attribute indicating which index in the array they correspond to (this definitely seems more work than the other suggestions though).  Then you could use reflection to map the array to the properties by inspecting the attributes.

```
public class MyClass {
    [ArrayIndex(1)]
    public string a {get; set;}

    [ArrayIndex(2)]
    public string b {get; set;}

    public void ProcessData(IEnumerable<string> input) {
        // loop through input and use reflection to find the property corresponding to the index
    }
}
```

Comment: See, now this answer has some real promise.  Add a private `GetVal` method like in @TGH's answer, and I think this would be production quality.  Nice.

Comment: @Dylan Smith - Beautiful! I did not know about the ArrayIndex attribute!

Comment: It's a custom attribute, you'll have to create it yourself.